# jQuery Ajax navigation without refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found the following library: https://4nf.org/installation/ which makes navigation through the pages of the site without reloading the page.

The instructions say that i need to connect the library:

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/arvgta/ajaxify@7.6.1/ajaxify.min.js"></script>`

and at site JS add `jQuery('#nav, #content').ajaxify();` after `.ready(function)`.

I make this, add `jQuery('#contentBox').ajaxify();` at my site JS, add at my site blade.php file `<div class="content" id="contentBox">`, But the ajax crossing do not occur. That is, in the browser line the site address changes, but I can’t go to the page where I use `<div class="content" id="contentBox">`, content doesn't change.

Where can be problem? I try to use it wil laravel app.

Comment: There are a lot of possibilities - what have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I don’t even know what to output to `concole.log()` :(